# How to reset input text values to defaults?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a page where an a4j:commandbutton captures the values of 2 textboxes. The textboxes values are defaulted this way:

```
 <a4j:region id="pnreg" >
  <h:inputText id="pn" binding="#{bean.pn}"
  value="Enter Number..."       
  onclick="clickclear(this, 'Enter Number...')"/>      
  </a4j:region> 
  </td>   
  <td width="20">
  <a4j:region id="qtyreg" > 
  <h:inputText value="Enter Part Qty..." id="qty" binding="#{bean.qty}"       
  onclick="clickclear(this, 'Enter Qty...')"/>      
  </a4j:region>
  </td>      
  <td width="20%">
  <a4j:commandButton id="addPart" render="pn,qty" value="Add Part"
   action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

When the page first loads the textboxes show the default values and when user clicks in them the values are cleared as coded. When the button is clicked, I would like the textboxes to return to the default values. Using jquery I think I need to add a click event handler, but the richfaces api already has an event handler attached to the a4j:commandbutton. How do I make my jquery eventhandler work with richfaces eventhandler? Thanks.

Comment: in ordinary HTML using forms and inputs, this is done by simply creating an input with the type of "reset", which will appear as a button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new JavaScript function that call's clickclear() on your text fields.  Then modify the a4j:commandButton, add an oncomplete="yourNewFuction();" attribute so your new function gets executed when your AJAX call completes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these a shot and get back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set back the values of the inputText, then you should add your js function in the `onclick` method of the `a4j:commandButton`:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="addPart" value="Add Part"
    onclick="alert('Before the ajax submit...');verifyInputTexts();"
    action="#{bean.submit}"
    render="pn,qty" limitToList="true"
    oncomplete="alert('Ajax completed!')" />
```

In that code sample, `verifyInputTexts` could be your JS function to validate your HTML using javascript. One more thing, the way I've written the attributes for the `a4j:commandButton` are in the order they get executed, the `limitToList="true"` is to tell that the ajax should only rerender the components in the `render` value .

Answer (score 0):

Put the inputText inside of same form as the "cancel" button and use type="reset"
ex:

```
    <h:form id="globalNotificationSettingsForm"> 
       your input <h:inputText>
       <a4j:commandButton id="cancelButton"
         ....other tags..
        render="globalNotificationSettingsForm"
        immediate="true"
        type="reset"/>
 </h:form>
```